# I want to read a String sentence from a Textfield and compare each letter in the String to my list

Tags: java

I want to read a String sentence from a Textfield and compare each letter in the String to my list of already made strings which look like this:

```
A = 123f;
B = 221d;
H = 2333gg;
```

And so on..

My question is: how can i read my message as individual strings lets say this is the message: `"Hello World"`

i want to be able to compare every word to my strings that i have made:
so "Hello World" it would compare the first letter "H" and it would make it into what i defined "H" to be, So it would output in a `JLabel` or anything else as `2333gg`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Is this homework? If so it needs the `homework` tag.

Comment: @Brian No its not homework im stuck at the point of comparing the String sentence from a TextField to each letter i know the rest, i just need a way to compare the String sentence to my own list of Strings letter by letter.

Comment: @Ahmedo - The general way it works here is you post the code you've worked out so far, and then ask for help. Your description as-is is a bit unclear; you say "how can i read my message as individual strings" and "want to be able to compare every word" but then start talking about individual letters.

Comment: @Brian My bad, By words i mean letters my English is not perfect

Comment: That's ok - I'm sure your english is better than my <any other languange>.

Comment: @Brian This is my first time asking for help, any idea on how to make it into a (for loop) to read each letter individually and output what they equal to in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to store your letters (A = ..., B = ..., H = ...) into a `Map`, then you iterate through the input letters (that you can get from the input string using `toCharArray()`), and if the `Map` contains the letter as a key, you output the corresponding value. Something like this:

```
Map<Character, String> lettersMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
lettersMap.put(Character.valueOf('A'), "123f");
lettersMap.put(Character.valueOf('B'), "221d");
lettersMap.put(Character.valueOf('H'), "2333gg");

String input = "Hello world";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
char[] inputLetters = input.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < inputLetters.length; i++) {
    Character letter = Character.valueOf(inputLetters[i]);
    if (lettersMap.containsKey(letter))
        sb.append(lettersMap.get(letter));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: @MarcoS Thank you! but this only reads the last letter not all of the letters in the output i only get the last letter

Comment: @Ahmedo93: it reads all the letters in your input, but "Hello world" contains only a H that matches with the content of the `Map`. Try it with `String input = "Hello AHmedo93 And Bye Bye!";`. You can also add other letters inside the `Map`.

Comment: @MarcoS im using it like this: String input = jTextField1.getText();

Comment: @Ahmedo93: fine! you're reading the text from your text-field. So, just ensure that the `Map` is properly initialized with all the letters that you may want to match against. For example, if you're interested in matching the content of your text-field with all the capital letters from A to H, then you have to initialize the `Map` with them by doing `lettersMap.put(Character.valueOf('A'), "123f");', 'lettersMap.put(Character.valueOf('B'), "...");', etc.

Comment: @MarcoS i only get the last letter im not getting the letter in front when i Type: "Hello Bye" i get 221d only but im looking for a way to give me the H and B so it shows : '2333gg221d' like that

Comment: @Ahmedo93: it works for me: for "Hello Bye" I get "2333gg221d". Note that I've changed `println` with `print` in the code above, so that you get a single output string without new lines. If you don't want to print things out while you match, you can concatenate the result of matching in `StringBuffer`, and then print out its content at the end of the `for` loop

Comment: @MarcoS this is what i have entered : 
`String input = jTextField1.getText();
char[] inputLetters = input.toCharArray();
for (int ii = 0; ii < inputLetters.length; ii++) {
    Character letter = Character.valueOf(inputLetters[ii]);
    if (lettersMap.containsKey(letter)){
        jTextArea1.setText(lettersMap.get(letter));
    }
}`

Comment: @Ahmedo93: I'm suspect that `jTextArea1.setText()` overwrites the entire content of your text-area, so that you see only the last matched letter. Trying using a `StringBuffer` (see my modified code above), and then update your text-area only at the end, after the `for` loop.

Comment: @MarcoS Thank you very much! it works now! again thank you! your a life saver!!

Comment: @Ahmedo93: so, I guess the problem was really the way you were updating your text-area. I'm happy that it works now, and I hope you learned something useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `String` (let's call it `myString`), you can iterate through the letters like so:

<strike>for (final char c : new StringIterator(myString)) 
    {
        // Do something with each character (c)
    }</strike>

Does that help?

**Edit:** I'm *SO* sorry - I was using a non standard library in a piece of code and forgot.

How about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
{
    char c = myString.charAt(i);        
    //Process char
}
```

Comment: @no it didn't work im not familiar with StringIterator maybe thats why

Comment: Ack! SOrry - I was using something that wasn't standard. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.toCharArray()` to get an array of chars, where you can access each char individually.

```
String[] charArray = userInput.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: you don't need `split` for coverting a `String` to a `char[]`: `toCharArray()` does exactly that.